# TreeView selected node problem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

i wanted to create a custom treeview so i inherited the treeview class and created 'CustomTreeView' class

there i implemented multiselect concept..

for making the node as selected,

```
node.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
node.ForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
```

i used these lines...

but the problem is when i make the control as disabled(ie enabled=false),

the selected node goes invisible..

any other solution to make a node selected??? without this enabled problem?

**EDIT:** Here is the full function that is called when a node is selected:

```
private void ToggleNode(TreeNode node, bool bSelectNode)
{
   if (bSelectNode)
   {
      m_SelectedNode = node;

      if (!m_SelectedNodes.Contains(node))
         m_SelectedNodes.Add(node);

      node.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
      node.ForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
   }
   else
   {
      m_SelectedNodes.Remove(node);
      node.BackColor = this.BackColor;
      node.ForeColor = this.ForeColor;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some of your code? From the way I understand your description, I can't reproduce this problem. A disabled `TreeView` control still respects the custom `BackColor` and `ForeColor` properties set to individual nodes.

Comment: private void ToggleNode(TreeNode node, bool bSelectNode)
  {
   if (bSelectNode)
   {
    m_SelectedNode = node;
    if (!m_SelectedNodes.Contains(node))
     m_SelectedNodes.Add(node);
    node.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
    node.ForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
   }
   else
   {
    m_SelectedNodes.Remove(node);
    node.BackColor = this.BackColor;
    node.ForeColor = this.ForeColor;
   }
  }

Comment: is function will be called when the node is selected

Comment: and when the application which hav this customtreeview is disabled.. the node's text goes invisible

Comment: Have you specified a custom `BackColor` and/or `ForeColor` for your `TreeView`? Those could be similar enough to the highlight colors that it's causing them to look invisible. With a standard white `BackColor` and black `ForeColor` for my `TreeView`, combined with my system's green `Highlight` color and white `HighlightText` color, I cannot reproduce this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's because Highlight and HighlightText are sufficiently close together that you get this effect with the dimming.

Try Red and Blue. Does it still disappear?